# How to get all collections and documents without their names in Cloud Firestore (web)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For example, I have database with this structure:

- Solar system (collecton)

  - Earth (document)

    - Eurasia (collection)

      - France (document)

        - population: 65 000 000
        - area: 640 000
      - Germany (document)
      - Russia (document)
    - South America (collection)
    - Africa (collection)
  - Venus (document)
  - Mars (document)

If I use this code:

```
db.collection("Solar system").doc("Earth").collection("Eurasia").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc);
            });
        });
```

I will get a list of countries in console:

- France
- Germany
- Russia

But what if I don't know all position in my database and I just want to get all positions in collections?

For example I don't know how many continents in my collection "Earth" and I want to print the list of all countries in all continents in console.

Another words, how can I not specify the name of collections and documents in query?

```
db.collection("Solar system").doc(?????).collection(?????).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use root level collections:

```
 - Planets
     - Earth { id: earth }
     - Venus { id: venus }
     - Mars  { id: mars }
 - Continents
     - Europe { id: europe, planet: earth } 
     - Asia   { id: asia, planet: earth }
 - Countries
     - Germany { id: germany, continent: europe, planet: earth }
     - France { id: france, continent: europe, planet: earth }
```

According to your question "For example I don't know how many continents in my collection "Earth" and I want to print the list of all countries in all continents in console.", with this structure you can do this this way:

```
db.collection("Countries").where("planet", "==","earth")
```

All countries for "Europe" continent:

```
db.collection("Countries").where("continent", "==", "europe")
```